# Editing XSD or XML Files in IntelliJ IDEA is Really Slow

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd

I'm trying to edit an `XSD` file in `IntelliJ IDEA` but it's extremely slow to the point that it freezes for a couple of seconds after typing a character. The file is about 500 lines long so size shouldn't be the issue.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Note: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24715

It occurs when editing an `XSD/XML/properties` file having the `Structure View` open. When editing the file, `IntelliJ` attempts to regenerate the structure on the fly, causing the freezes.

---

**Solutions**:

1. Update to the latest version of IntelliJ as the bug seems to be
   fixed in newer versions.
2. Failing solution 1, closing the `Structure View` will fix the issue:

   - Locate the `Structure` tab on the left hand side. It should look like the below.
   - Right click it -> Remove from Sidebar

[image: Structure Tab Image]